# Unless not working for static images stored in my file system in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am developing a mean stack application and all my images come from NodeJS server that is stored in the Images folder of it.

I have restricted my API calls by using unless to only access by using authorization token but few of my API are put into unless the function of express jwt but I am not able to get the images as it gives the `error: 401` even putting the API route in unless

Below is my NodeJS code patch:

Unless function

```
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless( 
    { path: ['']
    {url:'/api/imageAPI/', methods: ['GET']},]
}

app.use('/api/imageAPI/Images/', 
express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../../Images/')));
```

Comment: what you mean by `Unless function`?

Comment: unless is a function in express-jwt if we specify a route in this fuction with its method the api call is made open without aithorization token

Comment: Not sure will help but just have a look at:https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-unless

Comment: I already have this in my package.json

Comment: I am not able to understand how to use app.use(static.unless(function (req) {
  var ext = url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname.substr(-4);
  return !~['.jpg', '.html', '.css', '.js'].indexOf(ext);
}));

Comment: my guess: At the same file where you have added existing configuration, BTW You can open an [issue](https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless/issues) on here so the owner will help